# Order a MySQL query by fastest response time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT number, ResponseTime, TicketCreateTime, 
       round(time_to_sec(timediff(ResponseTime, TicketCreateTime))/60,2) AS FRMins
FROM (SELECT TE.id, T.number, T.ticket_id, TE.thread_id, TE.pid, T.created AS TicketCreateTime, TE.created AS ResponseTime, TE.type, TE.staff_id 
      FROM ost_ticket T INNER JOIN
           ost_thread_entry TE
           ON T.ticket_id = TE.thread_id
      WHERE TE.type = 'N' OR
            TE.type = 'R'  AND TE.id IN (SELECT min(id) FROM ost_thread_entry WHERE type = 'N' OR type = 'R' GROUP BY thread_id)
    ) AS FTRT_tbl;
```

```
number responseTime         TicketCreateTime  FRMins   
120985 2019-09-02 14:28:00  2019-09-02 14:10:00  18.0   
120985 2019-09-02 14:32:00  2019-09-02 14:10:00  22.0  
123490 2019-11-03 16:18:00  2019-11-03 16:17:00   1.0     
123490 2019-11-03 17:18:00  2019-11-03 16:17:00  61.0
```

But my goal is to have only one of the number and it should be this one with the lowest FRMins. I tried it in many different ways, but I don't get it right.

It should look like this one

```
number responseTime         TicketCreateTime  FRMins  
120985 2019-09-02 14:28:00  2019-09-02 14:10:00  18.0   
123490 2019-11-03 16:18:00  2019-11-03 16:17:00   1.0
```

Comment: Add some line breaks to the query. It is very hard to read it as it is now.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (As formatted text, no images...)

Comment: `where TE.type = 'N' OR
            TE.type = 'R'  AND TE.id IN ( ...)` is evaluated as `where TE.type = 'N' OR
            (TE.type = 'R'  AND TE.id IN ( ...))`, as intended?!?

Comment: R is Response  and N is a comment in the Table Structure, like if you write a comment, that you called someone it should mark it as Responded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ... GROUP BY ... HAVING)` subquery to get the distincts `number`s having the lowest `FRMins` :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  `number` INTEGER,
  `responseTime` DATETIME,
  `TicketCreateTime` DATETIME,
  `FRMins` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test
  (`number`, `responseTime`, `TicketCreateTime`, `FRMins`)
VALUES
  (120985, '2019-09-02 14:28:00', '2019-09-02 14:10:00', 18.0),
  (120985, '2019-09-02 14:32:00', '2019-09-02 14:10:00', 22.0),
  (123490, '2019-11-03 16:18:00', '2019-11-03 16:17:00', 1.0),
  (123490, '2019-11-03 17:18:00', '2019-11-03 16:17:00', 61.0);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM test t
  GROUP BY t.number
  HAVING FRMins = MIN(t.FRMins)
);
```

Output :

```
| number | responseTime        | TicketCreateTime    | FRMins |
| ------ | ------------------- | ------------------- | ------ |
| 120985 | 2019-09-02 14:28:00 | 2019-09-02 14:10:00 | 18     |
| 123490 | 2019-11-03 16:18:00 | 2019-11-03 16:17:00 | 1      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uGu7KxZGVw6MAMAFt9ouay/0)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one row, does this do what you want?

```
select t.*
from ost_ticket t
order by t.FRMins
limit 1;
```

Comment: Check edited question, OP need to remove duplicated `number` and keep only those who have the lowest `FRMins`